# SQL Server query to check if booking is available for particluar timeslot on a specific date

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a booking table where I store booking information. We allow booking on for two different time-slot during day let us say at 10:30am & 04:00pm on work days & for particular slot we only take  maximum of 50 visitors only.

*Details of sample table & data are show below*.

Based on sample data we can't take booking for `2012-08-23/16:30` as it has reached the maximum number of visitors.

Following query will get me the date that I need to block on the calender for specific time so that user can make booking for this date.

```
 SELECT 
     SUM(NoOfVisitors) as Total, TimeSlot, BookingDate, BookingCancelled  
 FROM 
     VisitorBooking  
 GROUP BY 
     BookingDate, TimeSlot, BookingDate, BookingCancelled 
 HAVING 
     SUM(NoOfVisitors) >= 50 AND TimeSlot = '16:30'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Total TimeSlot  BookingDate BookingCancelled
50    10:30     2012-08-23  0
```

I am having problem in writing a SQL query which will check if their is any cancellation and will calculate & give me dates which I need to block. I tried few query but that is not giving me the desired result. If I run the above query it will also show me `2012-07-20` as blocked while it still has availability for 3 more visitor as one of the booking has been cancelled.

This query gives me the results but i am not completely sure if this is correct

```
 SELECT 
     SUM(NoOfVisitors) as Total, TimeSlot, BookingDate, BookingCancelled  
 FROM 
     VisitorBooking  
 GROUP BY 
     BookingDate, TimeSlot, BookingDate, BookingCancelled 
 HAVING 
     (SUM(NoOfVisitors) >= 50 AND TimeSlot = '16:30' )
AND (BookingCancelled = 'false')
```

I am lost in this i would appreciate help in this regard

I am not sure if I can achieve this without using CTE query.

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
    BookingID nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(150) NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(150) NULL,
    Email nvarchar(150) NULL,
    CompanyName nvarchar(200) NULL,
    Country nvarchar(150) NULL,
    Phone varchar(50) NULL,
    NoOfVisitors int NULL,
    BookingDate date NULL,
    TimeSlot varchar(12) NULL,
    BookedOn datetime NULL,
    GUIDNo varchar(50) NULL,
    BookingCancelled bit NULL,
    )
```

**Sample data**

```
BookingID   FirstName LastName Email    CompanyName Country Phone   NoOfVisitors    BookingDate     TimeSlot    BookedOn    GUIDNo  BookingCancelled
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1900221519  Mark    Tailor  abc@abc.com     XYZ     USA     111111  45              2012-07-20       10:30       2012-06-25 XXXXX   false
5600515751  Michael Brown   abc@abc.com     XYZ     UK      111111  2               2012-07-20       10:30       2012-06-25 XXXXX   false
1638934678  John    Lee     abc@abc.com     XYZ     UK      111111  3               2012-07-20       10:30       2012-06-25 XXXXX   true
8852224170  Lee Wong        abc@abc.com     XYZ     China   111111  50              2012-08-23       16:30       2012-07-15 XXXXX   false
```

Comment: Second Query i have added seems to be working fine in my case i would still appreciate if someone can give a better option.

Comment: Your query is fine, but I would suggest removing `BookingCancelled` from select list and moving `TimeSlot` and `BookingCancelled` filters to where, like [this example @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/477bb/9). Note: I have changed TimeSlots in sample data to provide more records for testing.

Comment: @Nikola, I would also appreciate if you can tell me if your query will improve performance or is it more clean way of doing it. You query works fine as i have tested it with actual data.

Comment: Probably not, because most of the bookings will not be cancelled, and there is only two values in `TimeSlot`. But generally one should use having to filter aggregated values only, because having is executed after aggregations.